# Python - Group By and filter for attribute value missing

Tags: python

I have a list where some items doesn't have an attribute like `item["transitioned_to"] = 'Ended'` and I would like to count how many items are missing this value.

I'm able only to count how many items HAS "Ended" attribute: `data_filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x['transitioned_to'] == "Ended", steps))` - each `Ended` is relative to single `execution_id`.

How is possible to aggregate this list by `execution_sid` and count how many items are missing `item["transitioned_to"] = 'Ended'`?

As input example:

```
[{
    'execution_sid': 'sid1',
    'transitioned_from': 'step_a',
    'transitioned_to': 'step_b',
}, {
    'execution_sid': 'sid1',
    'transitioned_from': 'step_b',
    'transitioned_to': 'Ended',
}, {
    'execution_sid': 'sid2',
    'transitioned_from': 'step_a',
    'transitioned_to': 'step_b',
}]
```

In this example, should return 1 for each case: 1 HAS ended and 1 HASN'T ended. Is possible to perform this count using python?

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail? I can't really understand the problem. But from I understand, you have a chain of steps, some of them having the last one `Ended`, instead of next stem? If yes, is the input in order (as in, first entry for sid1 is where we start, then each other should match `to` of the previous with `from` of the next, until there are no more entries or there is `Ended`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'execution_sid': 'sid1', 'transitioned_from': 'step_a', 'transitioned_to': 'step_b', },
       {'execution_sid': 'sid1', 'transitioned_from': 'step_b', 'transitioned_to': 'Ended', },
       {'execution_sid': 'sid2', 'transitioned_from': 'step_a', 'transitioned_to': 'step_b', }]

res = defaultdict(int)
for d in lst:
    res[d['execution_sid']] += d['transitioned_to'] != 'Ended'

print(dict(res))
```

The output (aggregated by `execution_sid`):

```
{'sid1': 1, 'sid2': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = [{'execution_sid': 'sid1', 'transitioned_from': 'step_a', 'transitioned_to': 'step_b'},
           {'execution_sid': 'sid1', 'transitioned_from': 'step_b', 'transitioned_to': 'Ended'},
           {'execution_sid': 'sid2', 'transitioned_from': 'step_a', 'transitioned_to': 'step_b'}]


print(Counter([item['execution_sid'] for item in my_list if item['transitioned_to'] != 'Ended']))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'sid1': 1, 'sid2': 1})
```